# Where has my Gmail message gone after I removed it?

Tags: gmail

I was on Gmail this morning, and I opened an email on my iPhone, which I had opened before on my phone and desktop.

While selecting an important email, my thumb went towards the top right and pushed the screen.I can no no longer find that email anywhere. I must have at 16 categories down the left hand side I have checked each one: All, zol, d, sent , inbox, outbox, social, forum, and it's gone.

Answer (score 3):

Your mail has been archived. That happens if you press on mail title and slide right. You can find archived mails in left menu - All mail

More info here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your question, the answers can many and for this i inviate you to see this link...

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7015314?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Here some steps:

Gmail messages are missing

This page can help you find your emails if:

Some emails are missing.Emails aren't coming to your inbox.Your inbox is empty and all your emails have disappeared

Emails might skip your inbox if they were accidentally archived, deleted, or marked as spam.

Follow these steps to search all your emails, including those that aren't in your inbox:

1 On your computer, open Gmail.

2 In the search box, click the Down     arrow .

3 Click the All Mail drop down, then select Mail & Spam & Trash.

4 Enter some information that’s in the missing email. If you're not sure about exact words or details, leave the fields blank.

5.At the bottom of the box, click Search

---

Check if the email was filtered

You may have created a filter that automatically archives or deletes certain emails.

Here's how to check your filters:

1 From a browser, open Gmail.

2 In the top right, click Settings Settings.

3 At the top, click the Filters and Blocked Addresses tab.

4 Look for filters that include the words "Delete it" or "Skip Inbox."

5 To the right, click Edit or Delete.

6 Follow the on-screen instructions

Other istruction are on the link above

Comment: Please add the details/instructions in the body of your answer instead of just linking to an outside resource, as it might change or disappear altogether.

Comment: Thanks Ferdinando, If it is still missing after checking  your suggestions? What then....

Comment: We have more information and we can use other alternative...for example control your mail if you have two o more account...Add comment and we will help you...together we will find the solution...

Comment: Thanks for including the information in your answer.  As a final step, please blockquote, that is use `>` in front of any text that you are using verbatim.  Thanks!